# setValue for a combobox in Jest dont work

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js

I having a testcase in Jest where I want to set a value for a Combobox from Vuetify. But the value is not set, please help!

So Im doing it this way:

```
            <v-combobox
              id="product"
              v-model="form.product"
              background-color="white"
              outlined
              dense
              label="Product"
              :items="products"
              item-text="name"
              item-value="name"
              :return-object="false"
            ></v-combobox>
```

And in testcase:

```
await wrapper.find('input[id="product"]').setValue('Data');
```

but the expect

```
expect((wrapper.vm as any).form.product).toBe('Data');
```

Will say:

```
Expected: "Data"
Received: ""
```

So the setValue dosent seems to work for a combobox, it works good with a normal input, a select or text-area. Please help!

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are testing  your own code. You seem like testing vuetify's code here in that you are making sure that when the input changes it emits event to update `v-model`. They already tested it. If you still want to know how, check their tests for it: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.6.3/packages/vuetify/src/components/VCombobox/__tests__/VCombobox.spec.ts

Comment: No im not testing vuetify, what I want it to set a value in a combobox and then press a save button and see what parameters that are sent to backend. But since the setValue dont work for comboboxes the value is not set, and the parameter to backend are empty. So I need a way to set a text to the combobox.

Comment: you set a value to combobox by setting the `value` prop or `v-model`. That's how components work. you dont interact with the dom manually.

Comment: Your testcase is setting input element of Combobox manually and then asserting it updated your property. You are then testing Combobox rather than your own code. You're trying to do this: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.6.3/packages/vuetify/src/components/VCombobox/__tests__/VCombobox.spec.ts#L291

Comment: what you want might be solved by: setting the value on whatever you're passing to Combobox and then executing your save function and then assert your expectations. Whether you use Combobox or some other component, it won't matter because you are testing your logic and not the component.